# How to test method with ActiveRecord::Base.transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord, transactions

I want to test the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions, class_name: 'RevisionState'
  def _update(book_params)
    assign_attributes book_params
    if valid?
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        revisions.create!(state: 'draft') if save!(book_params) # save then create
        # ....get create! to raise an exception
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am using Minitest, but that shouldn't matter. Also, I prefer to do this without relying on some additional gem - i.e. just good ol' Ruby if possible.

One idea is to override (redefine) `Book.save!` (`ActiveRecord.save!`) and `RevisionState.create!` (`ActiveRecord.create!`), the other is to inject a filter (e.g. `after_save`) that forces an exception.

**test/models/book_test.rb**:

```
require 'test_helper'
class BookTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test '_update transaction' do
     # do some normal stuff
     # ...

     # And now do something to get RevisionState.create! to raise an exception
     # when it is called below (via ._update)   <-- need help

     assert_difference('RevisionState.count', 0) do
       assert_raises(RuntimeError) {
         book._update({title: 'raise hell'})
       }
     end

     book = Book.find(book.id)
     refute_equal 'raise hell', book.title
  end
end
```

The above works, except I am raising the exception in **app/models/revision_change.rb**:

```
after_save { |i| raise 'hell' if Rails.env.test? && i.book.title == 'raise hell' }
```

Obviously such a hack is undesirable in my app, hence why **I want to do it in runtime in my test**.